# How to create a NSMutableDictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create an NSMutableDictionary to use the key chain in iOS, but I'm getting the following error.

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

This is the code I'm using:

```
var keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, service, userAccount, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecMatchLimitOne], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecReturnData, kSecMatchLimit])
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

the complete code:

```
import UIKit
import Security

let serviceIdentifier = "MySerivice"
let userAccount = "authenticatedUser"
let accessGroup = "MySerivice"

class KeychainService: NSObject {

    class func saveToken(token: NSString) {
        self.save(serviceIdentifier, data: token)
    }

    class func loadToken() -> NSString? {
        var token = self.load(serviceIdentifier)

        return token
    }

    class func save(service: NSString, data: NSString) {
        var dataFromString: NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        // Instantiate a new default keychain query
        var keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, service, userAccount, dataFromString], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecValueData])

        // Delete any existing items
        SecItemDelete(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef)

        // Add the new keychain item
        var status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef, nil)
    }

    class func load(service: NSString) -> NSString? {
        // Instantiate a new default keychain query
        // Tell the query to return a result
        // Limit our results to one item
        var keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, service, userAccount, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecMatchLimitOne], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecReturnData, kSecMatchLimit])

        var dataTypeRef :Unmanaged<AnyObject>?

        // Search for the keychain items
        let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)

        let opaque = dataTypeRef?.toOpaque()

        var contentsOfKeychain: NSString?

        if let op = opaque? {
            let retrievedData = Unmanaged<NSData>.fromOpaque(op).takeUnretainedValue()

            // Convert the data retrieved from the keychain into a string
            contentsOfKeychain = NSString(data: retrievedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        } else {
            println("Nothing was retrieved from the keychain. Status code \(status)")
        }

        return contentsOfKeychain
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is to do with the variables that you're passing to the dictionary. Can you show their declarations?

Comment: Since that's an `NSDictionary` init method, can you try `NSDictionary(objects:...,keys:...).mutableCopy()`?

Comment: please see the update, I have included the whole code now. @Jack wu no unfortunately that does not work

Comment: I see, the problem should lie in the parameters then. The Array you are making is of type `Any[]`, but it takes `AnyObject[]` as an argument.I would try wrapping those in `NSValue`s. I'll test it out in Playground and draft an answer later

Comment: I've pasted your code into OS X playground and it works...

Comment: The code works, are you using Beta 1 or Beta 2?

Comment: that is equivalent to an `NSMutableDictionary` instance in _Swift_: `var mutableDictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary()`

Comment: hi, I'm using Beta 2 and it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

For your code you can use a **NSDictionary** that way:

```
    var keychainObjects = NSArray(objects:"\(kSecClassGenericPassword)", service, userAccount, dataFromString)
    var keychainValues = NSArray(objects:"\(kSecClass)","\(kSecAttrService)", "\(kSecAttrAccount)","\(kSecValueData)")
    let keychainQuery = NSDictionary(objects: keychainObjects, forKeys: keychainValues)
```