# Socket.connect() is not consistent when using connectParams with JWT

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, jwt

I'm using https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt to connect the user to my node.js/socket.io server and I'm using one round trip

My problem right now is that whenever user logs in on the IOS part, the `socket.connect()` is not consistent, my theory is that the token is not yet ready even before the `socket.connect()` gets invoked.

I'm using Singleton design for my Socket.io class as many people pointed that out.

Here's the code on the `SocketManager.swift` part

```
import SocketIO

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()
    var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": getToken()])]) // getToken() I got it from other file which is Constant.Swift

    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }       
}
```

I'm using [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) to store the token and Constant.Swift file store all the global variables and functions so that I could call it on any Swift files.

**Constant.Swift**

```
import Foundation
import KeychainAccess

let keychain = Keychain(server: "www.example.com", protocolType: .https)

func getToken() -> String {
    if let token = keychain["token"] {
        return token
    }
    return ""
}
```

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func facebookButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
       Alamofire.request("/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)

                    self.keychain["token"] = String(describing: json["token"])
                    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection() 
                    self.segueToAnotherVC() // Segue to another screen, to simplify things i put it in a function
                }
        }
}
```

So technically what is happening in this controller is, when the user logs in, I will store the token into KeychainAccess (it is equivalent to NSUserDefaults), then only I will make a socket connection because the socket connection needs a token beforehand.

What should I do to make the connection consistent all the time, whenever user logs in? Any methods that I could use?

Comment: Does it work fine if you use NSUserDefaults instead of Keychain access? Have you tried it already? 
Also, I would suggest you to check if getToken method is returning the correct token.

Comment: Additionally, I think you should use keychain like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324285/adding-items-to-and-querying-the-ios-keychain-with-swift`

Rest of the code looks fine to me, But for KeyChain I'm not sure if you are using it right way

Comment: @MohnishHirudkar it does return the correct token I already check it, because when I establish the connection in `app.delegate` it works, I believe the creation of the token time is the problem here.

Comment: @sinusGob have you tried switching `.log(false)` to `.log(true)` to see if any additional debug information is printed? To me, this could also *possibly* be due to the `Alamofire` async callback being in a non-main thread, and `SocketIO` I *think* needs to be on the main thread. LMK if either of those things help :)

Comment: Are you opening up this socket connection on the same `URL` that alamofire is connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use keychain like this:

```
let keychain = KeychainSwift()
keychain.set("string", forKey: "key")
keychain.get("key")
keychain.delete("key")
```

keychain Usage:

```
let saveBool: Bool = KeychainWrapper.setString("String", forKey: "key")  
let retrievedString: String? = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("key")
let removeBool: Bool = KeychainWrapper.removeObjectForKey("key")
```

And make sure that your token is set when calling establish connection, if not, don't try and connect.

References:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/788

https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift

https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper

More info:

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) Web Token is a JSON-based open standard for creating access tokens that assert some number of claims.